# Возможно ли (BaaS) типа Scorocode обрабатывать заголовками multipart/form-data?

Tags: javascript, node.js, parse.com

Решил сменить backend платформу мобильного приложения на scorocode! Вопрос собственно в том, что приложение для отправки данных использует multipart/form-data заголовки, а в HTTP API сервиса явно указаны application/json. Возможно я чего-то не понимаю, т.к. узнал о сервисе лишь день назад. По Вашему, реально ли выполнить подобную адаптацию?

Comment: не хочу ни на кого клеветать, но работал со скорокодом, в общем, поищите еще варианты)

Comment: Если не секрет, что Вас в ней оттолкнуло? Как я понял, остальные все буржуйские! Возможно у Вас есть на примете вменяемая BaaS платформа?